# Can I set "id" of button to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set a button's id to a variable, so that I can easily get access to changing numbers of buttons:

```
<script>var test = 1; </script>
<button id=test> click me </button>
```

but it is does not work. 
my motivation to do this : 
I read from a xml file and display part of them using form. and then I have to change the value of them. and the number of items I read from xml is not fixable. so if i want to control them i need give each item a number.

Comment: It's worth noting that an `id` attribute cannot, under the HTML 4 doctype, begin with a numeric character and be a valid HTML 4 document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var button = document.getElementsById("test");
```

Your var 'button' will contain the DOM object with the id 'test'.  You might wanna do this a little more 'dynamic' something like:

```
var myArray = [];

var oButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var i = 0;
for(i=0;i<oButton.length;i++) {
 if (oButton[i].className == 'likedButton') {
   myArray.push(oButton[i]);
 }
}
```

This way, you simply need to add "class='likedButton'" to your button and this will add all those button into the array 'myArray'.  Next step if you wanna do anything to those button, just go throught the 'myArray' object myArray[0] showing the first object with the class 'likedButton'.  I suggested the class attribute so that you can easily find tons of button.  If you use the ID attribute, all IDs MUST be different.

Answer (score 3):

```
var test=1;
var ele = document.getElementById('test');
ele.id="button_" + test;
ele.value="button " + test;
```

Just to be clear, when you say

```
<button id=test/>
```

or, for that matter, the more standards-compliant

```
<button id="test"/>
```

the word `test` is just a text identifier.  It is not interpreted as javascript.

The only place (I know of) where you can put javascript directly into an HTML attribute and it will be interpreted, is an event handler (such as `onclick`) or in the `href` of an `a` tag, after the prefix `javascript:`.

Comment: Note that the prefix `javascript:` is only to be used in a `href` attribute; not in event handlers!

Answer (score 0):

What you've done in your code is assign the `id` value "test" to the element.

It sounds like you're already dealing directly with DOM elements, so you can just assign the value to their `id` property. Example:

```
var list, li, index;

// Find a list that already exists on the page
list = document.getElementById('myList');

// Add four items to it
for (index = 0; index < 4; ++index) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.id = "listItem" + index; // listItem0, listItem1, ...
    li.innerHTML = "I'm list item #" + index;
    list.appendChild(li);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eyata4)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly set the dom objects id to to a javascript variable but you can can change the id using javascript or jQuery I'm not totally clear on what your trying to do. but I htink what your saying is that you want to change id based on the number of buttons to do that use jquery foreach

```
$('button').each(function(key,value){
    $(this).attr("id","button_"+key)
});
```

Comment: *"I don't think you can directly set the dom objects id to to a javascript variable..."* Yes, you can. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder so  you could do <input id="globalvariable" /> like that ?

Comment: I think you're both saying the same thing in your answers

Comment: Sure: `<script>document.writeln("<input id='" + globalvariable + "'>");</script>` But you don't need to, you can do it later, modifying the markup.

Comment: Lol ohh ok I see lol ic but that's nor the same ad putting a js var in HTML directly but I gotcha

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change it immediatly inside of the Button ID. Have to change it after the Button.

```js
var button3 = "button3"+i
var button4 = "button4"+i
      '<button id="button3" type="submit" class="accpet-button">Accept</button></td><td>'+
      '<button id="button4" class="cancel-button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></td>'
  +"</tr>");
var ele = document.getElementById('button3');
ele.id="button3"+i;
var ele = document.getElementById('button4');
ele.id="button4"+i;
i++;
document.getElementById(button3).disabled = button1;
document.getElementById(button4).disabled = button2;
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, seems that you're missing something in 3rd line